# tooltipHtml - extract from google maps call

Tags: iphone, regexkitlite

" (2.1\x26#160;mi / 7 mins)"

I have the above string and I need to get to the distance and time only. How would I go about doing this using the RegexKitLite script? Ideally, the below is what I'm looking for:

time = 7 mins
distance = 2.1 miles

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with RegexKitLite script but I've done it this way:

NSString* tooltipHtml = [apiResponse stringByMatching:@"tooltipHtml:\\"([^\\"]*)\\"" capture:1L];

```
NSLog(@"tooltip Html: %@", tooltipHtml);


int leftParanthesis = [tooltipHtml rangeOfString:@"("].location;
int inverseSlash = [tooltipHtml rangeOfString:@"\\"].location;
int slash = [tooltipHtml rangeOfString:@"/"].location;
int semiColumn = [tooltipHtml rangeOfString:@";"].location;
int rightParanthesis = [tooltipHtml rangeOfString:@")"].location;


NSRange distanceRange = NSMakeRange(leftParanthesis+1, inverseSlash-leftParanthesis-1);
NSString *distance = [tooltipHtml substringWithRange:distanceRange];

NSRange distanceTypeRange = NSMakeRange(semiColumn+1, slash-semiColumn-1);
NSString *distanceType = [tooltipHtml substringWithRange:distanceTypeRange];

NSRange timeRange = NSMakeRange(slash+1, rightParanthesis-slash-1);
NSString *time = [tooltipHtml substringWithRange:timeRange];
NSString *distanceCompact = [distance stringByAppendingString:distanceType];

NSLog(@"Distance %@:", distance);
NSLog(@"Distance type %@:", distanceType);
NSLog(@"Time %@:", time);
NSLog(@"distance Compact %@:", distanceCompact);
```